# How to fetch JSON object from Json array in REstAssured

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

**Can anyone please help me to solve this scenario:**

I am new to `RestAssured` and handling `JSON` in our automation script.
I have an `API` whose response is `JSONArray` i.e.,

```
  [{
    "id": 1002,
    "entity": "testcase",
    "fieldName": "TextName",
    "displayName": "Name"
  }, {
    "id": 1003,
    "entity": "testcase",
    "fieldName": "steps",
    "displayName": "TestSteps"
  }]
```

While automation, for verification i need to fetch the reponse.
I have tried the below one but not getting expected output

```
 String API = "/field/entity/testcase"
 Response response = given().auth().preemptive().basic("test.manager",     "test.manager").when().get(API);
    JSONObject JSONResponseBody = new   JSONObject(response.body().asString());
    Assert.assertEquals(JSONResponseBody.getString("fieldName"), "TextName");
```

and also i tried with this:

```
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    JsonObject JSONResponseBody = array.getJsonObject(0);
```

Thanks Inadvance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try this:

```
String API = "/field/entity/testcase"
Response response = given().auth().preemptive().basic("test.manager", "test.manager").when().get(API);
JSONArray JSONResponseBody = new   JSONArray(response.body().asString());
Assert.assertEquals(JSONResponseBody.getJsonObject(0).getString("fieldName"), "TextName");
```

Answer (score 13):

These kind of validation can achieve directly using restAssured - ValidatableResponseOptions itself

```
    String API = "/field/entity/testcase"
    given().auth().preemptive().basic("test.manager", "test.manager").
    when().get(API).
    then().assertThat().body("fieldName[0]", equalTo("TextName");
```

Note - 
"equalTo" validation needs following static import

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just as another idea of how to do this, I would do it maybe like this instead:

```
ValidatableResponse statusResponse = givenJsonRequest().when()
    .get("/field/entity/test").then();
ArrayList<Map<String,?>> jsonAsArrayList = statusResponse.extract()
    .jsonPath().get("");
Optional<Map<String,?>> filtered = jsonAsArrayList.stream()
    .filter(m -> m.get("fieldName1").equals("Whatever1"))
    .filter(m -> m.get("jsonObject").toString().contains("Whatever2"))
    .findFirst();
Assert.assertTrue(filtered.isPresent(), "Test expected a result after filtering.");
```