# RestAssured: how to extract field inside JSON array

Tags: java, arrays, json, rest-assured

I know a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35263637/how-to-fetch-json-object-from-json-array-in-restassured) has been posted, however, the answer didn't work for me.

I am using RestAssured. How do I convert my `Response` into a JSON object and then extract a field that is within the JSON array (in my case, inside the `errors` array)?

```
Response response = 
           given().
                contentType(ContentType.JSON).
                body(jsonAsMap).
           when().
                post("/customers").
           then().
                statusCode(400).extract().response();
   //get "code" field inside "errors".
```

When testing the request in Postman, I get this result:

```
{
  "uri": "/customers/",
  "query": null,
  "method": "POST",
  "contentType": "application/json",
  "status": 400,
  "statusMessage": "Bad Request",
  "errors": [
    {
      "field": "firstName",
      "code": "firstName.required", //need to extract this field
      "message": "firstName is required"
    }
  ]
}
```

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JsonPath to access the value and convert this into a Java type.

Something like this:

```
String errorCode = ...then().extract().jsonPath().getString( "errors[0].code" )
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer, here is an alternate solution:

```
String errCode = ...then().extract().path("errors[0].code");
```